# Generate list of unique random numbers in Swift from range

Tags: swift, random, arc4random

I would like to write a function which should return list of integer. Integer list size and max Random number will be defined by user, which user will pass through function parameter. My special requirement is, integer into list can not be redundant.
My approach using `Array`:

```
func getRandomNumbers(maxNumber: Int, listSize: Int)-> [Int]{
    var randomNumbers = [Int]()
    for _ in 1...listSize{
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(listSize)))
        randomNumbers.append(randomNumber)
    }
    return randomNumbers
}
```

Problem: Sometimes i am getting duplicate values with this approach.
I know swift `Set` doesn't hold duplicate value.

My approach using `Set`:

```
func getRandomNumbers(maxNumber: Int, listSize: Int)-> Set<Int>{
    var randomNumbers = Set<Int>()
    for _ in 1...listSize{
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(listSize)))
        randomNumbers.insert(randomNumber)
    }
    return randomNumbers
}
```

Problem: Sometimes `Set` size is less then user defined size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 problems here:

1. You don't generate enough numbers. You need to keep generating random numbers until your set is large enough:

   ```
   func getRandomNumbers(maxNumber: Int, listSize: Int)-> [Int] {
       var randomNumbers = Set<Int>()
       while randomNumbers.count < listSize {
           let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber+1)))
           randomNumbers.insert(randomNumber)
       }
       return randomNumbers
   }
   ```
2. You're biasing your random numbers by putting them in the ordering Set chooses, which is highly predictable. You should append your numbers to an array (to keep them in order that they are generated), while still leveraging a set in parallel, for its fast deduplication:

   ```
   func getRandomNumbers(maxNumber: Int, listSize: Int)-> [Int] {
       precondition(listSize < maxNumber, "Cannot generate a list of \(listSize) unique numbers, if they all have to be less than \(maxNumber)")

       var randomNumbers = (array: [Int](), set: Set<Int>())

       while randomNumbers.set.count < listSize {
           let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber+1)))
           if randomNumbers.set.insert(randomNumber).inserted { // If the number is unique
               randomNumbers.array.append(randomNumber) // then also add it to the arary
           }
       }

       return randomNumbers.array
   }
   ```

Comment: You probably should also check that `maxNumber` is less than `listSize`, so you don't try to produce something like 100 unique random numbers in a range of 0 to 10.

Comment: Inserting check on my func, no assumption any more.

Answer (score 6):

Swift 5 version implementation

```
extension Int {

    static func getUniqueRandomNumbers(min: Int, max: Int, count: Int) -> [Int] {
        var set = Set<Int>()
        while set.count < count {
            set.insert(Int.random(in: min...max))
        }
        return Array(set)
    }

}
```

For example:

```
let uniqueNumbers = Int.getUniqueRandomNumbers(min: 1000, max: 1500, count: 10)
```

An example result:

```
[1454, 1105, 1305, 1176, 1498, 1127, 1310, 1209, 1373, 1198]
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use while count is less than listSize instead of a for loop, not e that you need to pass maxNumber plus one instead of listSize to arc4random_uniform:

```
func getRandomNumbers(maxNumber: Int, listSize: Int)-> Set<Int> {
    var randomNumbers = Set<Int>()
    while randomNumbers.count < listSize {
        let randomNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(maxNumber+1)))
        randomNumbers.insert(randomNumber)
    }
    return randomNumbers
}

getRandomNumbers(maxNumber: 10, listSize: 3)  // {5, 7, 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens when you get a duplicate random number. Instead of generating listSize random numbers, you could check randomNumbers.count and generate random numbers until it reaches listSize.

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another possibility. I don't claim this is the best, but it seemed to me that `IndexSet` could be a good way to solve the problem (basically, this idea nerd-sniped me and I had to find an answer), and this is what I came up with.

```
func getRandomNumbers(maxNumber: Int, listSize: Int)-> [Int]{
    guard maxNumber < listSize else { return [] }
    var indexSet = IndexSet(integersIn: 0...listSize)
    var randomInts = [Int]()

    while randomInts.count < maxNumber {
        guard let currentInt = indexSet.integerLessThanOrEqualTo(Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(listSize)))) else {
            continue
        }
        randomInts.append(currentInt)
        indexSet.remove(currentInt)
    }
    return randomInts
}
```

The idea is to create an `IndexSet` covering 0 to the requested max value, and then randomly remove elements from that set until you have enough of them. It avoids duplication by removing integers from the set as they are used. `IndexSet` is not actually a `Set`, it's an efficient way of storing a bunch of unique integers, so it gets the uniqueness of a `Set` without actually creating a `Set` containing all integers in the range.